# Python: Reading binary file with date/time

Tags: python, binaryfiles

I have part of a binary file that represents a start time.

I am trying to read a time/date value in the file in Python but having trouble.

```
>>>file = open('file1',"rb")
>>>data = file.read()
>>>data[16:24]
b'Q\xca\rk\x9c\xc6\xd7\x88'
>>>unpacked, = unpack('<Q', data[16:24])
9860568284264254033
```

I already know that 16-24 location contains Int64 of 8 byte size.

in C#, I can successfully get the value {3/12/2020 11:45:40 AM} by doing

```
var value = _reader.ReadInt64();
sdatetime = DateTime.FromBinary(value);
```

Does anyone know how to read it correctly in Python?

Also if it helps,

```
>>> unpack('q',data[16:24])
(-8586175789445297583,)
>>> unpack('Q',data[16:24])
(9860568284264254033,)
```

I tried doing:

```
>>> unpacked
9860568284264254033
>>> secs = unpacked / 10.0 **7
>>> secs
986056828426.4253
>>> delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds = secs)
>>> delta
datetime.timedelta(days=11412694, seconds=66826, microseconds=425293)
>>> ts = datetime.datetime(1,1,1) + delta
```

which just resulted in OverflowError: date value out of range

Comment: Could you please edit the question and post the complete code and show how you're reading the file?

Comment: Well from looking at the C# documentation on the [`DateTime.FromBinary()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.frombinary?view=netcore-3.1) It looks like two bits are used to store the locality (Kind property) and the remaining 62 bits are the number of ticks from the beginning of the 21st century. Extract these number of ticks and perform some weird python datetime.timedelta math and you can figure out your answer I believe.

Comment: I'll post the math I attempted, but it popped with error message saying OverflowError: date value out of range

Comment: @akb515 That timedelta is incorrect, a quick sanity check shows that you are looking at a time delta of roughly 31,267 years. Figure out which 62 bits are used to store the number of ticks, determine the time conversion between ticks and seconds, then perform a timedelta on a datetime object representing January 1, 2001.

Comment: @plum0 How would I figure out which 62 bits are used? The conversion seems to be 10 million ticks in a second from what I see on the Ticks Documentation for DateTime

Comment: @akb515 My guess is it would be either the upper/lower 2 bits are used. One article I'm reading claims the kind bits to be encoded in the upper 2 bits, meaning the lower 62 is your amount of ticks.

Comment: @akb515 just take a time of your choice and convert it to 62 bits using Ticks Docs and a calculator, and convert that time into 64bit binary using C#, the position of digits in 64bits which match your manually calculated number are the ones you need to extract. Ugly math but would work, i guess.

Comment: Or as @plum0 suggested try the first 62 and last 62, quite probable its either one of them.

Comment: @plum0  Okay will do. What do you mean by upper/lower 2 bits, is that the digits, like not including first two or last two digits? Sorry I'm not too good with Python.

Comment: @Zircoz Yeah I could try the math out and see where it leads me

Comment: @akb515, plum meant first or last two bits out of the 64 are being used to store the locality, hence your required 62 bits would be first 62 bits or last 62 bits.

Comment: You are decoding 8 hex bytes (64 bits) into a long in little endian format (the '<' part of your unpacking). This would mean that the lower bits ( or least significant bits) would be the right side of the binary representation of that number. Now you need to create a mask to extract the 62 least significant bits. In other words the number represented in binary as 62 1's.

Comment: @plum0 Thank you so much I think I figured it out. I converted the int to binary, took everything but first two bits, and then converted that segment into int, and got a similar number to the number of ticks for that specific date I found through a datetime to ticks converter I found online.

Comment: @Zircoz thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @akb515 I'm a bit confused on what you mean by converting the int to binary. Integers are already binary, but binary is a different way of representing them that is less readable to humans and more readable by machines. If you mean you converted the int to a bytestring and then did some weird string splitting to remove the bits I would urge you to see my answer to understand how you can work with the number itself and not the string representation. While working with strings is easy and will work, it is potentially less efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've figured it out

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

time_bytes = b'Q\xca\rk\x9c\xc6\xd7\x88'
time_int = int.from_bytes(time_bytes, 'little')
time_bin = bin(time_int)

# remove two unrelated bits and convert to integer number of ticks
n_ticks = int(time_bin[:2] + time_bin[4:], 2)
secs = n_ticks / 1e7

d1 = datetime(1, 1, 1)
t1 = timedelta(seconds=secs)
print(d1 + t1)
```

outputs:

```
2020-03-12 15:45:40.947823
```

So it's correct up to the time zone

#### EDIT:

To get an actual timezone, use `timedelta` once more.

```py
zone_delta = timedelta(hours=-4)
print(d1 + t1 + zone_delta)
```

gives

```
2020-03-12 11:45:40.947830
```

Comment: I just saw the comment that @akb515 came up with the same solution. Anyways, maybe someone will use it later.

Comment: For timezone, since I know it should be 11:45AM, how would I change the last three lines . its a 4 hr difference so where would include this change?

Comment: just added it to the solution

Comment: A little simpler: `n_ticks = time_int & 0x3fffffffffffffff`, using bitwise `&` to clear the top two bits. The hex value is `(1<<63) - 1`. (Too bad there isn't a nicer way to specify a 64-bit mask, though.)

Comment: I agree this is a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

We ran through a lot of this information in the comments but here is an answer in case comments are removed/deleted.

[DateTime.FromBinary()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.frombinary?view=netcore-3.1) converts C# datetime objects into binary by encoding 62 lower bits as ticks since January 1, 2001 (start of 21st century) and the 2 upper bits as locality/Kind information. This means that we need to extract the 62 lower bits before we can use them. Then we simply convert these seconds into a timedelta and perform the arithmetic to retrieve our python datetime object.

Now there will be a margin of error here because the Kind information that we are ignoring is used to determine timezone. You could dive deeper and look into what the Kind bits are and see if you can retrieve the timezone to be more consistent in your result, but for this answer I have not.

```
unpacked = unpack('<Q', data[16:24])
# 64 bits with two most significant bits as 0 is decimal: 4611686018427387903
# Here I am performing a bitwise mask to keep only the 62 least significant bits.
# I prefer this method in stead of string manipulation from bin() for potential memory efficiency reasons
ticks = unpacked & 4611686018427387903
# There are 10,000,000 ticks in a second
seconds = ticks / 10000000
td = datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)
epoch = datetime.datetime(year=1, month=1, day=1)

resultDate = td + epoch
```